# What determines input /output impedance of a transistor configuration

Tags: transistors, impedance

I cannot intuitively get any answer about how **CE CB CC** have different **output/input impedance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the AC voltage is the same but AC current is buffered by hFE then the Emitter Follower or CC transforms impedance on the other side of base or Emitter by hFE in each direction looking in.   Thus Zin at Base is hFE larger than Emitter load and Zout of Emitter is hfe smaller than Rb (equiv) or Zbase (equiv)

A transistor circuit design can amplify voltage, or current or lower impedance or increase both V*I at same impedance.

It's like gears and torque or force or impedance from either side is transformed by gear ratio.

Answer (score 0):

CommonEmitter has output at the collector, which is modeled as a stiff current source with HIGH Rout. Early Voltage describes a slope, defining Rout.
CommonEmitter has input at the base, with Rin of Beta/GM or Beta * Ie/0.026.

CommonBase has output at the collector, and for reasons I don't remember, its an even stiffer current source. CB has input at the emitter, with Rin of 1/GM.

CommonCollector has output at the Emitter, with Rout of 1/GM + Rsource/Beta.
CC has input at the Base; Rin should be Beta * (Remitter||Rload + 1/GM)

Tony, why is CB stiffer than CE?